# New data connection created when changing connection string using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that contains a pivot table which is updated by a macro.  Before the data is refreshed, though, the connection string gets changed:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Connections("Data").ODBCConnection
    .Connection = [Redacted]
    .CommandText = "EXEC ExtractCases " & Client
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With
```

This seems to cause the pivot table to create a new connection (called either `Connection` or `Data1`, and I can't seem to figure out what it does to choose between them) and point itself to that.  So I then have to add lines like these:

```
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("Pivot").ChangeConnection ThisWorkbook.Connections("Data")
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("Pivot").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Which seems to work (except when it doesn't), but leaves a lot of dead connections knocking around the workbook causing confusion.

I've tried manually deleting the `Connection` connection, but then it suddenly names itself `Data1` itself for no apparent reason and the system gets upset because a non-existent `Connection` can't be deleted.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?  Is there some magic way to fix this so it doesn't create the second one in the first place to cause these kinds of headaches?

*Note:* I am running this code in Excel 2010, but the workbook has to be openable by 2003; however, I remove the VB module before distribution, so 2010 macro stuff is fine, it's just things in the workbook proper that might get tripped up by this...

Comment: Theres someting i did not yet fully understand. Do you change (have to change) the connection each time? Or is done magically by excel?

Comment: @cmmi: I need to change the connection each time - it's a report that's run for all the clients of our company, and each time it only has that client's data.

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the same problem in Excel 2010 (might be the same for earlier versions, I dunno).

I have tried the same approach as you i.e. changing the connection of the Pivot Table in the VBA-code AFTER I have edited the commandText of the connection string. As you, I noted sometimes success and other times failure.

I haven't been able to find out why the problem arises and in which cases the above mentioned approach results in success or failure.

**I have, however, found a working solution**:
In your VBA code, you need to perform the following steps in the said order:

1. Change the commandText (which as you know results in the creation of a new
   connection now in use by the Pivot Table).
2. Delete the old connection string.
3. Rename the connection string from step 1 to the name of the connection string deleted in step 2.
4. Refresh the Pivot Table.

NB: This only works if there is only one pivot table using the connection. If you have created extra Pivot Tables by copying the first one (i.e. they share the same Pivot Cache), the above mentioned procedure won't work (and I don't know why).

However, if you use only one Pivot Table with the connection string the approach will work.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that it is the update of the connection string that is causing your problem.  There is a bug when updating the `CommandText` property of an ODBC connection that causes an extra connection to be created.  If you temporarily switch to an OLEDB connection, update your `CommandText` property and then switch back to ODBC it does not create the new connection.  Don't ask me why... this just works for me.

I created a module that allows you to update the CommandText and/or Connection string.  Insert this code into a new module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateWorkbookConnection(WorkbookConnectionObject As WorkbookConnection, Optional ByVal CommandText As String = "", Optional ByVal ConnectionString As String = "")

With WorkbookConnectionObject
    If .Type = xlConnectionTypeODBC Then
        If CommandText = "" Then CommandText = .ODBCConnection.CommandText
        If ConnectionString = "" Then ConnectionString = .ODBCConnection.Connection
        .ODBCConnection.Connection = Replace(.ODBCConnection.Connection, "ODBC;", "OLEDB;", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
    ElseIf .Type = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB Then
        If CommandText = "" Then CommandText = .OLEDBConnection.CommandText
        If ConnectionString = "" Then ConnectionString = .OLEDBConnection.Connection
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid connection object sent to UpdateWorkbookConnection function!", vbCritical, "Update Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If StrComp(.OLEDBConnection.CommandText, CommandText, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        .OLEDBConnection.CommandText = CommandText
    End If
    If StrComp(.OLEDBConnection.Connection, ConnectionString, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        .OLEDBConnection.Connection = ConnectionString
    End If
    .Refresh
End With

End Sub
```

This `UpdateWorkbookConnection` subroutine only works on updating OLEDB or ODBC connections.  The connection does not necessarily have to be linked to a pivot table.  It also fixes another problem and allows you to update the connection even if there are multiple pivot tables based on the same connection.

To initiate the update just call the function with the connection object and command text parameters like this:

```
UpdateWorkbookConnection ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection"), "exec sp_MyAwesomeProcedure", "ODBC;..."
```

Comment: This solved my problem very neatly with no need to delete unwanted connections. Tested it with two connections, one with one pivot table and one with two.

Answer (score 1):

you may add this code, after you refresh connection.

```
With ThisWorkbook
    .RefreshAll
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Have a start date and end date field on the worksheet that is used to modify the period for the data in a pivot table. Added the following code for the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Update the query when the date range has been changed.
    If (Target.Row = Worksheets("Revenue").Range("StartDate").Row Or _
        Target.Row = Worksheets("Revenue").Range("EndDate").Row) And _
        Target.Column = Worksheets("Revenue").Range("StartDate").Column Then

        FilterTableData

    End If
End Sub

Sub FilterTableData()
    'Declare variables
    Dim noOfConnections As Integer
    Dim loopCount As Integer
    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim connectionName As String
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim strMonth As String
    Dim strDay As String
    Dim startDateString As String
    Dim endDateString As String

    'Remove current connections
    'Note: Excel creates a new connection with a new name as soon as you change the query for the connection. To avoid
    ' ending up with multiple connections delete all connections and start afresh.

    'First delete all fake connections
    noOfConnections = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count
    For loopCount = noOfConnections To 1 Step -1
        Set conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(loopCount)
        If conn Is Nothing Then
            conn.Delete
        End If
    Next loopCount

    'Then delete all extra connections
    noOfConnections = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count
    For loopCount = noOfConnections To 1 Step -1
        If loopCount = 1 Then
            Set conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(loopCount)
            conn.Name = "Connection1"
        Else
            Set conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(loopCount)
            conn.Delete
        End If
    Next loopCount

    'Create date strings for use in query.
    startDate = Worksheets("Revenue").Range("B1")
    strDay = Day(startDate)
    If Len(strDay) = 1 Then
        strDay = "0" & strDay
    End If
    strMonth = Month(startDate)
    If Len(strMonth) = 1 Then
        strMonth = "0" & strMonth
    End If
    startDateString = Year(startDate) & "-" & strMonth & "-" & strDay & " 00:00:00"

    endDate = Worksheets("Revenue").Range("B2")
    strDay = Day(endDate)
    If Len(strDay) = 1 Then
        strDay = "0" & strDay
    End If
    strMonth = Month(endDate)
    If Len(strMonth) = 1 Then
        strMonth = "0" & strMonth
    End If
    endDateString = Year(endDate) & "-" & strMonth & "-" & strDay & " 00:00:00"

    'Modify the query in accordance with the new date range
    With conn.ODBCConnection
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT INVOICE.ACCOUNT_PERIOD, INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER, INVOICE_ITEM.LAB, INVOICE_ITEM.TOTAL_PRICE, ", _
        "INVOICE.INVOICED_ON" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "FROM Lab.dbo.INVOICE INVOICE, Lab.dbo.INVOICE_ITEM INVOICE_ITEM" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "WHERE INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER = INVOICE_ITEM.INVOICE_NUMBER AND ", _
        "INVOICE.INVOICED_ON > {ts '" & startDateString & "'} AND INVOICE.INVOICED_ON < {ts '" & endDateString & "'} ")
    End With

    'Refresh the data and delete any surplus connections
    noOfConnections = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count
    If noOfConnections = 1 Then
        'Rename connection
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).Name = "Connection"

        'Refresh the data
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").Refresh
    Else
        'Refresh the data
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").Refresh

        'Delete the old connection
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection1").Delete
    End If

    'Refresh the table
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Revenue").Update
End Sub
```