# How to bypass "Select Data Source" Prompt For Query Tables w/ VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel, macros

I have a macro that exports queried data from SQL into a Query Table in Excel. The whole process is done through a macro and it's been set-up an ODBC connection. Since the connections are already set-up, essentially all I'm doing is updating some of the data in the command string in the macro and then refreshing it. Everything works fine when I run it on my computer; however it is used by multiple people on the same network. Although the macro associated with the query ultimately works fine for everyone, all users other than me are getting the "Select Data Source" and User Name/Password prompts.

Is there a way that I can set the macro to execute so that all users can run it without getting those prompts and without having to set-up the ODBC data source on their machine? I have been searching for hours to see how others have been able to bypass that prompt (ex. [How to disable the "Select Data source window in VBA"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823191/how-to-disable-the-select-data-source-window-in-vba)), but nothing I've found has worked for me.

Here's how the connection string is currently set for the connection:

```
"DSN=RTP;UID=J4;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;WSID=123;DATABASE=C;"
```

Here's how my macro currently looks like:

```
 Sub Vols_L()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim odbcCn As ODBCConnection, oledbCn As OLEDBConnection

    Set cn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Vols_L")

    Set ws = Sheets("Setup")
    Set ws6 = Sheets("L Graph")
    Set ws7 = Sheets("Queries")

    Dim Query As String
    Dim SSD As String
    Dim SED As String
    Dim PM As String
    Dim AD As String
    Dim ID As String

    Query = ws7.Range("Vols_L_Query")
    SSD = ws.Range("SSD").Value
    SED = ws.Range("SED").Value
    PM = ws.Range("FOM_PM").Value
    AD = ws.Range("AD").Value
    ID = ws.Range("ID").Value 

    Query = Replace(Query, "#SD", SSD)
    Query = Replace(Query, "#ED", SED)
    Query = Replace(Query, "#PM", PM)
    Query = Replace(Query, "#AD", AD)
    Query = Replace(Query, "#ID", ID)

    Updates the workbook Connection Depending on Type
    With cn
        If .Type = xlConnectionTypeODBC Then
            Set odbcCn = cn.ODBCConnection
            odbcCn.CommandText = Query
            odbcCn.Refresh

        ElseIf cn.Type = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB Then
            Set oledbCn = cn.OLEDBConnection
            oledbCn.CommandText = "Query"
            oledbCn.Refresh
        End If
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

EDIT: So the big problem I'm having is that I am apparently very stupid. I really appreciate your help, but I've tried every one of the different methods mentioned in the response below, and couldn't get any of them to work for me. I tried inputting the UpdateWorkbookConnection query into the one I pasted earlier (it replaced everything after the comment "Updates the workbook Connection Depending on Type") so that it looked like:

```
UpdateWorkbookConnection ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Vols_L"), Query, "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=C;Data Source=RTP;"
```

When I do that though, I get an error at the point in your macro that says:

```
".OLEDBConnection.Connection = ConnectionString"
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a different connection string, which does not require the ODBC connection to be pre-configured on each computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a DSN so if the user doesn't have that DSN configured on their machine with the exact name that you're using it won't know what to use.  You can do a [DSN-less](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/892490) connection string so that you don't have to go to every machine and set up the DSN.

A trick I use sometimes to build a connection string is to create a file on your desktop with the file extension ".udl".  When you double click it, you can select the provider and connection details and test if the connection works.  Then you can open up the ".udl" file in notepad and view the connection string that was built.

I use the VBA code below to change an excel command and/or connection string.  It works well and prevents a bug that sometimes [creates a new connection when modifying a connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943976/new-data-connection-created-when-changing-connection-string-using-excel-vba) in some cases.

```
Sub UpdateWorkbookConnection(WorkbookConnectionObject As WorkbookConnection, Optional ByVal CommandText As String = "", Optional ByVal ConnectionString As String = "")
'example usage
'UpdateWorkbookConnection ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection"), "EXEC sp_procedure"[, "optional connection string here"]

With WorkbookConnectionObject
    If .Type = xlConnectionTypeODBC Then
        If CommandText = "" Then CommandText = .ODBCConnection.CommandText
        If ConnectionString = "" Then ConnectionString = .ODBCConnection.Connection
        .ODBCConnection.Connection = Replace(.ODBCConnection.Connection, "ODBC;", "OLEDB;", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
    ElseIf .Type = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB Then
        If CommandText = "" Then CommandText = .OLEDBConnection.CommandText
        If ConnectionString = "" Then ConnectionString = .OLEDBConnection.Connection
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid connection object sent to UpdateWorkbookConnection function!", vbCritical, "Update Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If StrComp(.OLEDBConnection.CommandText, CommandText, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        .OLEDBConnection.CommandText = CommandText
    End If
    If StrComp(.OLEDBConnection.Connection, ConnectionString, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        .OLEDBConnection.Connection = ConnectionString
    End If
    .Refresh
End With
```